# Configure mapconfig.xml for null tag_value

Tags: pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

I am using [osm2pgrouting](http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html) version 2.3.6. When using osm2pgrouting for .osm file, I created tables ways. However, when I compared it with table planet_osm_line, it lost a lot of line.

I determined that all lines having "highway" = null were not generated in ways table. I think the root cause is all lines that configured in mapconfig.xml file will be generated. But in mapconfig.xml file, it only allows tag_value to be defines specific text, not null. Ex: tag_value name="motorway" id="101"

So, my question is:

1. Is my determination correct or not?
2. If correct, how can I define value null in mapconfig.xml so that the final ways table will not lose data.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/774234/125400

Comment: I think it does not depend on "how to create null value in xml file", it depends on the code osm2pgrouting has support this case or not. As my understanding, the code will select all rows in planet_osm_line table that has value = "motorway" at column "highway" to process (my example above). In my case, I want select all rows that has value = null at column "highway". How should I configure for mapconfig.xml file, or some one can help to modify the code that support my case?